# In which file, queue messages are stored in TIBCO EMS?

Tags: tibco-ems

Like queue names are stored in queues.conf file located in ems/bin folder....
Does any one know where does the messages on tibco ems queue are stored?
Can we access messages on these queues without any other tool?

Comment: Got it!!!
Those messages are stored in .db format files in "ems\bin\datastore".
async-msgs file, which is in .db format contains queue messages!! Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Go to Your stores.conf file under [store_name] you can find parameter file= path;
the path in front of file will give you path of file where messages get stored. you can change it.

Comment: Hi Makarand,
 I dont find the file **stores.config**. I searched it in ems directory but there is no config file with this name! Can you specify the file location.
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for delay.
If you are using windows 7 it's in configuration directory|
C:\ProgramData\TIBCO_HOME\tibco\cfgmgmt\ems\data .

You can check path of stores.conf in tibemsd.conf file (That is file you are giving for tibemsd.exe while starting ems server)